# How to fix a div background image hidden behind other divs in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, background-image

I have the following code...

HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">  
   <div id="slideshow">  
      <div> <!-- SLIDE 1 -->  
         //slide content  
      </div>  
      <div> <!-- SLIDE 2 -->  
         //slide content  
      </div>  
   </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery { 
   width: 940px; 
   height: 317px; 
   background: transparent url("../images/banner_bg.png") no-repeat scroll right 0; 
   position: relative; 
}
```

I have tried this with .png .gif and .jpg images for background, same result.
The problem is that in IE7 the slideshow div covers the background image from the gallery div. I know this because if I set the opacity of the slideshow div to 80 or less I can see the background image shining through.
The page looks great in firefox, chrome, safari and opera. This is only a problem in IE7 and IE8.
Does anybody know how to fix this? I have spent hours googleing this and have tried everything I came across no matter how unlikely it sounded. I have not been able to find a solution.

(Please help, this is making me insane)

Comment: Is this something you could put in a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: There has to be a solution for this other than re-writing... We place divs inside of divs on a regular basis and adding a background image to some or all of them is not a new concept. If I give the div a background color instead of an image, it works fine, it's only the image that is not showing...

Comment: I'm really not sure what exactly the problem is, that's why i was wondering about the fiddle.

Comment: I don't understand your question Angie.. Can you please clarify what you mean. I'm doing some work with a site at the moment that uses transparent layered divs on top of and around images and it works in IE.. So I'm not sure exactly what you're asking..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem...

The slide divs were getting their background color set to black and I am assuming that this is an IE interpretation because
1) it was not happening in other browsers and
2) I could not find anywhere in the code where it would have set the bg color to black.

The CSS fix was simple:

```
#gallery #slideshow div { background-color: transparent !important; }
```

I did have to add the !important to the end or it would overwrite my style.